Feasibility of a kivy app being able to pause videos, sound, etc., on other applications (e.g., pause TikTok videos)
My question is: How do I add something to my code that will pause videos on other applications (e.g., pause tiktok, facebook videos, etc.,) when my app 'pops up' in the bottom half of a person's phone screen (so the video isn't playing while they're reading my pop-up)?
Background:
I'm currently trying to develop a kivy app with python that 'pops up' on your phone after a set amount of time and asks you a question. I want my app to be able to pause whatever you were currently doing/on before my app popped up and be able to resume it when the 'pop up' disappears. My app will take up only the bottom half of the phone screen, so I still want the app the user was on (e.g., TikTok or something) previously to show up in the upper half, just with all audio and video paused. I don't want the user taken out of whatever app they were on when my pop up shows up.
I've tried to research about this but haven't found anything about it. I'm not an expert coder either so I wouldn't know anything really about apps accessing other apps but I have been told that there might be a legal thing/there's some software on phones and stuff that stops apps from accessing other apps but I don't know much about that to be honest.
The following is my code if you need it:
.py file:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
    
Window.size = (300, 300)

x = 1
checktimeout = 0

class MainScreen(Screen):
    answer = StringProperty("")
    answerhint = StringProperty("")
    answerhint = "Answer"
    answer = ""

    def on_enter(self):
        global x
        global checktimeout

        if checktimeout == 0:

            checktimeout += 1
            Clock.schedule_once(self.timeout, 10)
        else:
            pass

        if x == 1:
            self.q_change = "I have keys but no locks. I have space but no room. You can enter, but you can't go outside. What am I?"
            self.manager.get_screen('main').ids.questions.text = self.q_change
            self.answer = 'Keyboard'

        elif x == 2:
            self.q_change = "If you drop me, I’m sure to crack, but smile at me and I’ll smile back. What am I?"
            self.manager.get_screen('main').ids.questions.text = self.q_change
            self.answer = "Mirror"

        else:
            self.q_change = "What has hands and a face, but can’t hold anything or smile?"
            self.manager.get_screen('main').ids.questions.text = self.q_change
            self.answer = "Clock"
            x = 0 

    def resetText(self):
        global x

        if self.manager.get_screen('main').ids.answerInput.text == self.answer:
            App.get_running_app().root.current = 'correct'
            self.manager.get_screen('main').ids.answerInput.text = ""
            x += 1
            self.stoptimeout()

        else:
            App.get_running_app().root.current = 'retry'
            self.manager.get_screen('main').ids.answerInput.text = ""

    def stoptimeout(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.timeout)
        global checktimeout
        checktimeout = 0

    def timeout2(self, dt):
        global checktimeout
        checktimeout = 0
        App.get_running_app().root.current = "sound"

    def timeout(self, dt):
        self.manager.get_screen('main').ids.answerInput.text = ""
        global x
        x += 1
        Window.hide()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeout2, 2)

class CorrectScreen(Screen):
    pass

sound = 1
class PlaySoundScreen(Screen, Image):
    def on_enter(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.soundshow, 1)

    def soundshow(self, dt):
        global sound

        if sound == 1:
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('sound/stressrelief.mp3')
            sound += 1

        elif sound == 2:
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('sound/pianomusic.mp3')
            sound += 1

        elif sound == 3:
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('sound/nicebeats.mp3')
            sound = 1

        Window.show()
        if self.sound:
            self.sound.play()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.stopsound, 10)

    def stopsound(self, dt):
        Window.hide()
        self.sound.stop()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.startS, 3)

    def startS(self, dt):
        App.get_running_app().root.current = 'findhiddenobject'

Findobject = 1
class FindObjectScreen(Screen):
    x_position = NumericProperty()
    y_position = NumericProperty()
    image_source = StringProperty("")
    change_label = StringProperty("")
    def on_enter(self):
        global Findobject

        if Findobject==1:
            self.x_position = 0.024
            self.y_position = 0.35
            self.image_source = "findobject/findobject.jpg"
            self.change_label = "Find the Easter Egg!"
            Findobject += 1

        elif Findobject==2:
            self.x_position = 0.7
            self.y_position = 0.23
            self.image_source = "findobject/Spot-the-chick.jpg"
            self.change_label = "Find the Chick!"
            Findobject += 1

        elif Findobject==3:
            self.x_position = 0.75
            self.y_position = 0.38
            self.image_source = "findobject/find-the-ring.jpg"
            self.change_label = "Find the Ring!"
            Findobject = 1
        Window.show()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeoutObject, 10)

    def timeoutObject(self, dt):
        Window.hide()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeoutObject2, 2)

    def timeoutObject2(self, dt):
        App.get_running_app().root.current = "main"
        Clock.schedule_once(self.show, 1)

    def show(self, dt):
        Window.show()

    def stoptimeout(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.timeoutObject)

class WellDoneScreen(Screen):

    def wait(self):
        Window.hide()
        App.get_running_app().root.current = 'main'
        Clock.schedule_once(self.showMain, 3)

    def showMain(self, dt):
        Window.show()

class TryAgainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


def info_button(self):
    self.ids.info_button.text = u"⌫"
    self.ids.info_button.font_name = r"C:\Users\rosie\Downloads\arial-unicode-ms (2).ttf"

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    callFunc = MainScreen()

    def build(self):
        Window.borderless = True
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main"))
        sm.add_widget(PlaySoundScreen(name="sound"))
        sm.add_widget(FindObjectScreen(name="findhiddenobject"))
        sm.add_widget(TryAgainScreen(name="retry"))
        sm.add_widget(CorrectScreen(name="correct"))
        sm.add_widget(WellDoneScreen(name="welldone"))
        return sm

    def again2(self, dt):
        Window.show()

    def backtomain(self):
        Window.hide()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.appear, 3)

    def appear(self):
        Window.show()

    def again(self):
        Window.hide()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.again2, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()

Put short, is it actually possible to make my kivy app be able to pause tiktok, facebook and apps like those? And, if so, what is the code for this?
Any help is appreciated and I'm sorry if anything is unclear. As I've said, I'm not the best at coding but I'll try clarify anything that doesn't make sense.
Also, if it's not possible to pause the other apps, is there any other way I could have my app 'pop up' with the user being able to resume the video they were watching on whatever platform after my pop up goes away? Thanks again!

Can you add your code?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I've added my .py code (it's a bit long) and I've tried to specify the problem/question at the very start of the question, hope it's explained enough!
